# How to get associated changesets from build in TFS 2017?

Tags: c#, tfs, tfs-sdk, changeset

With c#, I was previously able to get associated changesets from TFS 2012 during a XAML build process using `InformationNodeConverters.GetAssociatedChangesets(IBuildDetail)`.  I got the IBuildDetail from `CodeActivityContext.GetExtension<IBuildDetail>()`.

Now that I'm using the TFS 2017 build processes, I am trying to do something similar with the code below, but it is not returning changesets.

```
var teamProjectCollection = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://ourtfsserver:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection"));
var versionControlServer = teamProjectCollection.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
var buildServer = teamProjectCollection.GetService<IBuildServer>();
var build = buildServer.GetBuild(new Uri(string.Format("vstfs:///Build/Build/{0}", "3807")));
var changeSets = InformationNodeConverters.GetAssociatedChangesets(build);
```

All of the above seems to work, and a build is returned successfully, but changeSets.Count() is 0, when in fact there should be some changesets returned.

Is there a suggested change to the code above, or an alternate way to do this?  Or does this just no longer work in TFS 2017?

Comment: Is it possible that I need to provide sufficient credentials to be able to view the changesets?  That would seem strange as I can successfully view other details about the build.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to do this by using what I believe are wrappers to the REST API: `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.WebApi.dll`

See: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/838da6a7-1dea-4d61-aaad-b789e23c64f2/how-to-get-associated-changesets-from-build-in-tfs-2017?forum=tfsgeneral

```
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.WebApi;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi;
using System;
using System.Net;

var u = new Uri("http://ourtfsserver:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/");
var c = new VssCredentials(new Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.WindowsCredential(new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain")));
var connection = new VssConnection(u, c);
var buildServer = connection.GetClient<BuildHttpClient>();
var changesets = buildServer.GetBuildChangesAsync("projectname", 3807).Result;
```

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft is updating TFS to use a REST API.  I think [this REST API call](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/builds#changes) will get you want you want.

Here's a link to the [.NET client libraries](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/get-started/client-libraries/dotnet) for making the REST calls.

Also, if you're not already aware, Microsoft is deprecating XAML builds.  See [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bharry/2017/05/30/evolving-tfsteam-services-build-automation-capabilities/) for more information.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear.  I'm not using XAML build processes anymore, but still running code to customize the builds.  I guess I'm looking for some specific way to grab the changesets, either through the REST API calls (which I haven't yet had success), or the client libraries that I'm attempting to use above.

Comment: There is also documentation for version 4.1-preview of the API: [Get Build Changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/build/builds/get%20build%20changes)